# Loading a JavaScript-library with RequireJS causes "ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, requirejs, webjars

I have a Scala/Play project that has React-dependencies loaded from http://www.webjars.org/npm in the build.sbt like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.webjars.npm" % "react" % "0.14.2",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "sweetalert-react" % "0.4.4",
)
```

React is loaded for the JavaScript like this:

```
requirejs.config({"paths":{"react":["/webjars/react/0.14.2/dist/react-with-addons"]}});
```

Here is [the actual react-with-addons.js-file](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/org.webjars.npm/react/0.14.2/dist/react-with-addons.js) that gets loaded from the WebJars. For React, it's sufficient to load it just using the paths-string for it, and it works nicely. However, for sweetalert-react loading it the same way causes some errors. Here is [the actual SweetAlert.js-file](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/org.webjars.npm/sweetalert-react/0.4.4/lib/SweetAlert.js) that gets loaded. The file is loaded like this:

```
requirejs.config({paths:{"sweetalert-react":["/webjars/sweetalert-react/0.4.4/lib/SweetAlert"]});
```

Trying to use it in a .jsx-file causes a following error:

```
define(['react', "sweetalert-react"], function (React, SweetAlert) {
   ...
}

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined; http://localhost:9000/webjars/sweetalert-react/0.4.4/lib/SweetAlert.js; 3; 1; ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

How should I configure the requirejs.config so that the SweetAlert.js works properly? I guess it should be configured somehow using the [RequireJS's shim -API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim), but I've been unable to configure it properly, as I'm still getting errors, though I haven't used RequireJS that much in the past. Sweetalert-react has several dependencies from sweetalert to React, but the error is coming from line 3 which just has

```
exports.__esModule = true;
```

Thanks for any answers :)

Comment: How did you move forward here?

Comment: Didn't manage to get this library issue fixed at all, just worked around it with a different library / own implementation.